# Python error no module named pygame eventhough it's installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed pygame with pip and it successfully installed.I even add it to the path.when I check it in cmd with py -m pip install -U pygame--user it works fine and shows that pygame is installed but when I want to run the code import python in idle it sends back an error that no module named pygame.I tried and figured out that if I write the code import pygame in the shell it works but if I want to try it in idle(or the shell that opens with running ths idle)it doesn't work. Can any one please tell me whats going on here and how can I make it work??
Btw both my python and pygame are for win64 and I'm using windows10

Comment: Do you only have one Python version installed?

Comment: try to run your script using **py script_path**, maybe you're executing script with another version of python? (if this will work then it proves that your actual way is using another python)

Answer (score -1):

The same things happened to me a few days ago. I fixed it by deleting Homebrew and then reinstalling it. I would go here for context:
https://brew.sh/